Stein Shakarchi Fourier Analysis Chapter 8 Exercise 7
I have the following question to solve.
Recall that for $|z|<1$,
\begin{align*}
    log_1\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{z^k}{k}.
\end{align*}
We have seen that
\begin{align*}
    e^{log_1\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}=\frac{1}{1-z}.
\end{align*}
a) Show that if $\omega=\frac{1}{1-z}$, then $|z|<1$ if and only if          $Re(\omega)>\frac{1}{2}$.
b) Show that if $Re(\omega)>\frac{1}{2}$ and $\omega = \rho e^{i             \phi}$  with $\rho>0\;,|\phi|<\pi$, then
\begin{align*}
        log_1(\omega)=log(\rho)+i\phi.
    \end{align*}
I heard that the a) part needs some difficult calculations, thus I wanted to ask, where I headed in the wrong direction with my proof. The following is my attempt to solve it.
Solution.
a) Let $z=x+iy$ and $|z|<1$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1-\bar{z}}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})}=\frac{1-x+iy}{(1-x)^2+y^2}
\end{align*}
and therefore
\begin{align*}
Re\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=Re\left(\frac{1-x+iy}{(1-x)^2+y^2}\right)=\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^2+y^2}>\frac{1-x}{1-2x+1}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, if $Re\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)>\frac{1}{2}$, we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^2+y^2}&&>\frac{1}{2}\\\\
&\iff\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;2(1-x)&&>1-2x+x^2+y^2\\\\
&\iff \:\;\;\;\;\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,\,\,\,\,\,1&&> x^2+y^2=|z|^2\\\\
&\iff\:\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,1&&> |z|.
\end{align*}
b) Let $\omega=\rho e^{i\phi}$ such that $Re(\omega)>\frac{1}{2}$, then take $z$ such that $\omega=\frac{1}{1-z}$, by a) $|z|<1$. Now Consider:
\begin{align*}
e^{log(\rho)+i\phi}=e^{log(\rho)}e^{i\phi}=\rho e^{i\phi}=\omega\\\\
\omega = \frac{1}{1-z}=e^{log_1\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}=e^{log_1(\omega)}
\end{align*}
Thus we have to have for $\phi$ mod $2\pi$:
\begin{align*}
log_1(\omega)=\log(\rho)+i\phi.
\end{align*}

The homography $h: z\to {1\over 1-z}$ extends to the Riemann sphere while setting $h(\infty)=0, h(1)=\infty$. As an homography $h$ sends a circle through $1$ in a line (a circle through $\infty$). As $h(-1)=1/2$, and $h(i)=1/2+i/2$ we see that the image of the circle $\vert z \vert =1$ by $h$ is the line $Re(z)=1/2$. So $h$ sends the interior (exterior) of the circle $\vert z \vert =1$, in one of the two half-spaces delimited by this line. As $h(0)=1$, we see that $h$ maps $\vert z \vert < 1$ bijectively to the half space $Re(z)>1/2$.

Cool proof!, but the Riemann sphere wasnt introduced into this book. Besides the question was more about if my proof is correct ?=)

Other argument. The homography $h$ is the composition of the translation $z \to z-1$, and the inversion $z\to 1/z$. The first one translate the circle through 1  to a circle through $0 $ (centered at $-1$). Now the map $z\to 1/z$ transform a circle through the origin to a line.
